# Redefine equation environment: auto labeling

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, environments

Hi i want to auto label every equation with its number (`\theequation`), i found a simple solution (to avoid manual environment redfinition) but i cant figured out what i am missing. Why it doesnt reconize the refrence ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\label{\theequation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x = y
\end{equation}
 Reference to the first equation: \eqref{1} (\theequation)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this really useful??? You're adding a label name which is precisely the equation number -- this is a) difficult to remember and b) might lead to multiply defined labels if the equation counter is not coupled to the chapter number or the chapter number is reset

Comment: in fact i am planing to add eq:\theeqation and even the chapter name so there will be no redefinitions, it's not dificult at all when i want to add a reference to an equation it's will be already ready, i only have to know the number of the chapter and the equation

Comment: The utility of the label is that you can add/ delete/move around the equation, and LaTeX will use the right label.  So, if you have one equation its label is 1, and `\eqref{1}` refers to it. If you add a second equation before the first, then, the `\eqref{1}` refers to the newly add equation not  the old one.

Comment: @Guido: Exactly my reasoning!!! (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because you use `\AtBeginEnvironment` to set the label, while the `equation` counter has not yet been stepped, meaning that the label `1` is not defined when you try to use it, only the label `0` is.

From the documentation:

> `\AtBeginEnvironment{<environment>}{<code<}`: Appends arbitrary `<code>` to a hook executed by the `\begin` command at the beginning of a given `<environment>`, immediately before `\<environment>`, inside the group opened by `\begin`.

If you really want to use this kind of labeling scheme, you can use `\AtEndEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}` instead. As explained in the `etoolbox` documentation, the `<code>` is executed just before `\end<environment>`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\AtEndEnvironment{equation}{\label{\theequation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x = y
\end{equation}
 Reference to the first equation: \eqref{1} (\theequation)
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

*Note:* This only works if your equation numbering is continous (and without "parent" counters included, as in e.g. `(2.1)`) throughout your document. If not, you will have to edit the `\label` argument correspondingly to avoid multiply defined labels.