# Insert portion of code before every line break in gather environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, cross-referencing, environments

This is a follow-up question to [Redefine equation environment: auto labeling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/305201/92620).

I want to have something like `\AtEndEnvironment{gather}{\label{equ:\theequation}}`(at the end) plus `\label{equ:\theequation}` before every line break `\\` inside a gather environment, ie add the portion of code `\label{equ:\theequation}`automatically in this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\AtBeginEnvironment{gather}{\label{equ:\theequation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
x = y \text{first equation (1)} \label{equ:\theequation}\\
...
y = z \text{(n-1)th equation (n-1)}\label{equ:\theequation}\\
y = z \text{nth equation (n)}
\label{equ:\theequation}
\end{gather}
Reference to the first equation: \eqref{1}... (even if the equation is a "gather" environment)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why would you ever want `\label{\theequation}` ?? An equation number would be the _last_ choice to use as a label, the whole point of `\label` is to use a symbolic name that is independent of the equation number,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i knew someone will say that comment, i edited the code

Comment: Even with the edit really it makes no sense it is a complete misuse of latex's cross referencing system to do this.

Comment: I do want the labels ready whenever i need them it much more easier to do it that way automatically i know how is named the label of each equation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even if i disagree let say it is a misuse, according to you what is the right way to use cross refrencing with equations in this case ?

Comment: So basically, you want to manually have edit every cross reference if you later on figure out that you need a numbered formula preceeding this one, because that is what you are essentially doing. You'll do that once and never do it again. Just make sure the labels are always unique no mater what code is added later on (that is why auto generation is so bad). Thumbs up for the context relevant prefixing though.

Comment: @daleif I dont want to do it manually (i can), what i did in the example code was just for illustration, what i want is a way to auto insert that piece of code in the right places the same as `AtBeginEnvironment` does but with some conditions.

Comment: That still will not help, they are not unique if another numbered formula is added later on. I simply do not understand why this should be a good idea

Comment: @daleif read this comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305201/redefine-equation-environment-auto-labeling#comment740318_305201

Comment: And you read the comments? Since `\theequation ` may change, those labels will not be stable. Say it starts as 1,so now your first eq has the label equ:1, and you refer to it. Later you change things and this particular eq now has number 2 and label equ:2, but the reference you made was to equ:1 so now you're no longer referring to the same equation. Thus you might as well not even use cross references.

Comment: The right way is just use a label like `\label{my-inductive-step}` or any other meaningful name unrelated to the number then use `\ref{my-inductive-step}` and let latex ensure that the correct numbers are used even if you add or remove equations and re-number the whole document. auto-generating the label negates the whole reason for the label mechanism to exist.

Comment: i admit you're right i didnt saw it from that angle because till now things are good and i didnt experienced some equation number shifting it would be a very bad news if it happened regarding the whole document; and it could easily happened if i remove/add an equation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that LaTeX has a `\label` mechanism at all is so that you can reference automatically numbered constructs without needing to know the number, and without having to change the reference markup when the number changes as the document is edited.

If you automatically label equation 2 as `\label{eq:2}` and refer to it as `\ref{eq:2}`  then your reference will reference whatever equation happens to have number 2 rather than the intended equation.

The intended use is that you label equations with an internal identifier meaningful to you,. say `\label{pythagorus}` and then refer to it as `\ref{pythagorus}` and the reference will generate the correct number, whatever that happens to be in the current (or actually, previous) edit of the document.