# Easy way to auto-label

Tags: cross-referencing

I defined a new paragraph with one counter in this way: `\def\newparagraph{\paragraph{\counter}}`
Is there a way to release this kind of label?

```
\label{\value{chapter}.\value{\counter}}
```

Comment: Please respect the [Markdown Format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help), you may want to read also [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/92620)

Comment: The purpose of a label is its easy to remember name, not `\label{2.3}`. I need no label then :-(

Comment: you may need to read [these comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305201/redefine-equation-environment-auto-labeling#comment740223_305201)

Comment: never use a numeric label, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: is that your actual definition? if `\counter` works in `\value` then it must be the name of a counter, so expand to something like `section` or `footnote` etc,  so `\newparagraph` always makes a section heading with the same text, the name of a counter????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can do

```
\newcounter{leo}
\newcommand{\newparagraph}{%
  \refstepcounter{leo}%
  \paragraph{\theleo}%
  \label{\thechapter.\theleo}%
}
```

but the label will serve no purpose whatsoever.

Suppose that, at one point when writing the document, your `\newparagraph` gets the number `4.1` (second numbered paragraph in chapter 4). You'll happily refer to it by `\ref{4.1}`. The next day, you decide that, after all, there should be another numbered paragraph *before* the already written one. You'll need to chase down all `\ref{4.1}` (and the ones of the form `4.x`) in order to change them for reflecting the current situation.

The next day you (or your thesis advisor) decide that, after all, the two numbered paragraphs should be merged into one. And so on and so forth.

Do, instead,

```
\newcounter{leo}
\newcommand{\newparagraph}{%
  \refstepcounter{leo}%
  \paragraph{\theleo}%
}
```

and use

```
\newparagraph\label{wonderful} This is my wonderful paragraph
```

so you can refer to it by `\ref{wonderful}`.

Comment: I'm sorry.. there is a way in order to make that the counter ''leo'' restart to ''1'' in each section? @egreg

Comment: @AndreaLeo `\newcounter{leo}[section]`